# vpn ibm-cloud MotionPro Client on Windows 10 not allowing addition of profiles

Tags: ibm-cloud, vpn

I am following steps to create a VPN, for accessing IBM Cloud, by using standalone client. Instructions are here,
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iaas-vpn?topic=iaas-vpn-standalone-vpn-clients

It states "Run the MotionPro Setup Wizard. Then, click the MotionPro icon on your desktop and select Profile > Add."

The installation ran fine - seemingly. I have a red A in my task tray and the Secure Tunnel is connected.
However, the Motion Pro window doesn't have any means for interaction - there are no menus - nothing...see screen grab.
I also don't have any MotionPro desktop on my desktop.

[MotionPro Window Screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBmPE.png)

So - MotionPro seems to have installed..but I still have to go thru the browser based logon process...so it's not really doing anything for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't figure out a way to create a profile using the MotionPro Client provided by IBMCloud.

Eventually found a download link to install myself...
https://support.arraynetworks.net/prx/001/http/supportportal.arraynetworks.net/downloads/downloads.html

I downloaded "Windows MotionPro client 32bit / 64bit"

After running the install, I then had a client executable that displayed a User Interface more like that which I expected and aligned to the steps in the IBMCloud documentation.

Created the profile - and can now quickly establish a VPN.